# Why isn't it redirecting to index.php with the .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration

Sorry for the inconvenience, I am new to PHP and I am trying to redirect with the .htaccess file to the public folder and inside that folder to the index.php file. What am I doing wrong? please I look forward to your support

[image]

> .htaccess

```js
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Proyecto_prueba/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I keep seeing the root with its two folders public and the app

[image]

Comment: Try with `Options FollowSymLinks`, `RewriteBase /` (or `RewriteBase /public/`, depending on which document root you've set) and (not so sure here) `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`.

Comment: It did not work out... :(

Comment: In the apache config file (like "httpd.conf") set the document root to the directory _"public"_: `DocumentRoot "/path/to/Proyecto_prueba/public" <Directory "/path/to/Proyecto_prueba/public">AllowOverride All Order allow,deny Allow from all</Directory>`. Then, in the file _".htaccess"_ inside directory _"public"_, remove the directive `RewriteBase ...` completely.

Comment: This modification will not affect other projects that have a different structure?

Comment: A good question. Yes, it would affect other projects, but only if you would not use [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) (here some [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)). My last comment presumed that you are already using a virtual host for each of your applications.

Comment: Try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` at the top of your .htaccess